# Armature mesh edit snaps back returning to Object mode

Tags: armature, shape-keys

In the attached blend file I am able to take a mesh modified by an armature and edit some vertices in Edit mode by disabling Shape Keys:

[image]

However, when I'm finished editing, the moved vertices snap back to their original position once I reapply Shape Keys or switch back from Edit to Object mode.

How do I make these edits persist?   FYI: The mesh and armature was imported from a DAZ file.

Blend file (too large for blend-exchange.giantcowfilms upload) is at [amatureMeshEdit.blend](http://optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/amatureMeshEdit.blend)

Comment: One should select the "Basis" shape key (not disable Shape Key Edit mode) before making any edit changes to the mesh, or add a new Shape Key, set value to 1 and select it before making edits.

Answer (score 0):

this [post](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-edit-mesh-like-in-pose-mode-position-object-mode/578064) was helpful for a better understanding of Shape Keys and the purpose of the 'Basis" key:

- select 'Basis' Shape Key
- in object -> Edit mode, make my modifications to the mesh
- exit object EDIT mode and the changes stick

[image: Shape Keys]

Comment: Thankfully this only took two days to figure out!